# Can't find lat long Brazil country

Tags: geolocation, geocoding, w3c-geolocation

I used `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` for geo location and i got lat long. But when i try to access Brazil country lat long using this method can't give me lat long.

Suggest me how to get lat long values in Brazil country.

**Code:**

```
<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script> var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() { 
   if (navigator.geolocation) {  
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition); 
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    } } 

 function showPosition(position) { 
      x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
    }
   </script> </body> </html>
```

Comment: This is hard to understand in its current form. Can you show some code and the results you're getting?

Comment: <p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
}
</script>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Can you edit the code into your question, and tell us what results you are getting?

Comment: i'm not getting any error message.if i try to access lat long in brazil  country i'm not getting any lat long but this code is working for all others country.

Comment: Well, what *are* you getting then?

Comment: first prompt display when  i'm clicking Allow Location then   not getting any lat and long

Comment: So you are in Brazil and it's not working on your machine? Is the machine capable of geolocation (e.g. with a built-in GPS)?

Comment: yes.my machine capable for geolocation

Comment: And when you are outside Brazil, it works? Have you tried a Geolocation example like this one: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp and confirmed whether it works?

Comment: yes. w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp link not work in brazil means not showing lat long.

Comment: Then it's your computer, or its connection - for example, it may not have anything to do geolocation with, like geographical information from the Wi-Fi router.

Comment: yes.in brazil i cant find my browser lat long

Comment: please give me a solution.

Comment: What for? I suppose you could somehow set up your router with geographical info, but I don't know how. It depends on many different things, the type of computer, the type of router, etc. - and it'd fix things *for your computer only*. If you need to have a location for development purposes, you can manually set one - see http://www.labnol.org/internet/geo-location/27878/